# Comparing odds of winning

Tags: probability

Started to play the national lottery and noticed I can play combinations of numbers instead of just plain 6 out of 49.

Since my math knowledge is fairly basic I am wondering which has the better odds:

- playing 10 numbers, and all their possible combinations of 6 (I believe it's 210)

or

- playing 210 simple variations of 6 numbers generated randomly